# Jquery UI combobox widget and jquery menu conflict

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I use JQuery UI combobox widget on same page with jQuery Menu (filament group http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ipod_style_and_flyout_menus/).

When I run page I get this error:

> Unable to get value of the property 'zIndex': object is null or undefined

I believe this is a conflict between these two plugins.

Has anyone else got the same error and solved the problem?

Comment: Not an answer, but the conflict makes sense; under the hood the autocomplete plugin uses a `menu` widget. Not surprising that the two conflict.

Answer (score 0):

I have just solved this problem. Change "menu" at `$.fn.menu` inside plugin, to another word. I changed it to `$.fn.menux`. Then change calling functions conveniently, like:

```
$('#flat').menux({
    content: $('#flat').next().html(), // grab content from this page
    showSpeed: 400
});

$('#hierarchy').menux({
    content: $('#hierarchy').next().html(),
    crumbDefaultText: ' '
});

$('#hierarchybreadcrumb').menux({
    content: $('#hierarchybreadcrumb').next().html(),
    backLink: false
});

// or from an external source
$.get('menuContent.html', function (data) { // grab content from another page
    $('#flyout').menux({ content: data, flyOut: true });
});
```